# Click event triggered twice on Galaxy Nexus

Tags: javascript, webview, dom-events, iscroll

I have a project with webview, using libs like iscroll, zepto.
The click event always triggered twice on Galaxy Nexus.
It works well on other devices.
I hope you can provide some advice.

Comment: you need a code example on what "fires twice" I have never had this issue on the nexus, and I can maybe provide you with some feed back. without even looking at your code, its a possible library conflict (some phones or verions of webkit disregard it) and the nexus probably doesn't. but a full list of libraries used and an "event" that fires twice would help.

Answer (score 1):

This may help point you in the right direction: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/iscroll/XL2Ny9gpKc0

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange. This is a [questions and answers site](http://stackoverflow.com/about), not a link collection. Please include relevant content in your answer, not just a link to where the content may be. The link is nice to have in addition for reference or for further information. For more tips, see [How to answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer).